# Find specific Month and Year between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I have two dates in the SQL table `Beg_date` and `End_date` including `Employee-ID`.

Need to pass two parameters `@Month` and `@Year` to find whether both `@Month` and `@Year` are between these `Beg_date` and `End_date`.

Example:

Passing values `@Month = '11'` and `@Year = '2014'`

Table data: `Beg_date = '10/1/2013'` and `End_date = '12/31/2014'`

Since, the `@Month` and `@Year` both comes in above dates, it should show the `Employee-ID`.

Now, if passing values `@Month = '11'` and `@Year = '2012'` to the above Table dates, it should not display the data.

One more thing that Employee has more than one record in the same table with different `Beg_date` and `End_date`; the script should search all the records before give the result

Example:

```
Employee-ID     Beg_date       End_date
-----------------------------------------
0001            01/01/2013     11/30/2013
0001            12/01/2013     11/30/2014
0001            12/01/2014     11/30/2015
```

Please advise...

Comment: `Mysql<>Sql Server` which one you are using?

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE - 2:

The query below should work for the problem described in your question for MS SQL 2005 environment. This solution bases mainly on datatype conversion using `CONVERT` function:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   tab
WHERE 
   CONVERT(DATETIME,
           LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Year)))
           + '-' + RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Month))), 2)
           + '-01', 120)
   >= CONVERT(DATETIME,
           LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), YEAR(Beg_date))))
           + '-' + RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), MONTH(Beg_date)))), 2)
           + '-01', 120)
   AND 
   CONVERT(DATETIME,
           LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Year)))
           + '-' + RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Month))), 2)
           + '-01', 120)
   <= CONVERT(DATETIME,
           LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), YEAR(End_date))))
           + '-' + RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), MONTH(End_date)))), 2)
           + '-01', 120)
```

It builds up valid `DATETIME` for given parameters `@Year` and `@Month` and for `Beg_date`, `End_date`. The example values compared in the `WHERE` taken from your example would be:

- `@Year`, `@Month`: **`2014-11-01 00:00:00`**
- `Beg_date`: **`2013-12-01 00:00:00`**
- `End_date`: **`2014-11-30 00:00:00`**

for which the condition would be satisfied.

You may find a working example on **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b24a63/2)**. It is done there for MSSQL 2008 (earliest available version there) but the syntax and functions should work on MSSQL 2005 also.

I hope it could help you some way.

> The previous version of this answer was based on my (wrong) assumption
>   that you use MySQL database.

Comment: Thank you, this work great! But I forget to mentioned that their are more than one records for the same employee in the same table with the different Beg_date and End_date. The script should search the month and year in all the records before gives the result. Please advise...

Comment: Hi. I'm glad it sligtly helped. As far as I understand well, the above query should search all the records in your table and for each of them check the condition in `where` clause, so I think it already do this - or am I missing something ?

Comment: For some reason, it's only searching between one record dates. Here's the example with three records: 1. Beg_date = 04/01/2013, End-date = 09/30/2013 2. 1. Beg_date = 10/01/2013, End-date = 09/30/2014 and 3. Beg_date = 10/01/2014, End-date = 12/31/2014. I search for month = 11 and year = 2013, it didn't show any result. Please advise...

Comment: I've corrected my answer - I hope it would give you the results.

Comment: Looks like PERIOD_DIFF(CONCAT)is not a built-in function in SQL Server 2005; could you please advise what other function I can use to replace PERIOD_DIFF(CONCAT)?

Comment: Hi Paul. Please find the updated answer based on your remarks - now it's for MSSQL 2005. I'm sorry for replying so late, but haven't had opportunity till now. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with `DATEFROMPARTS` function:

```
DECLARE @Month INT = 9
DECLARE @Year INT = 2014
DECLARE @ResultDate DATE

DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      [Employee-ID] CHAR(4) ,
      Beg_date DATETIME ,
      END_date DATETIME
    )


SET @ResultDate = CAST(CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(CAST(@Month AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))) + CAST(@Month AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '01' AS DATE)


INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '0001', '20130101', '20131130' ),
        ( '0002', '20130112', '20141130' ),
        ( '0003', '20140112', '20151130' )

SELECT  *
FROM    @t
WHERE   @ResultDate BETWEEN Beg_date AND END_date
```

Output:

```
Employee-ID Beg_date    END_date
0002        2013-01-12  2014-11-30 
0003        2014-01-12  2015-11-30
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2005 and getting the error while running your query ('DATEFROMPARTS' is not a recognized built-in function name.), please advise.

Comment: This works perfect; thank you so much for your help. I very much appreciate.